# How to calculate the indefinite integral of $(x-1)^{\frac 12}-(x-3)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Why is the following integral wrong?

$$ \int[(x-1)^{\frac 12}-(x-3)]dx=\frac 23 (x-1)^{\frac32}-\frac12(x-3)^2+c $$

The answer given by my textbook is:
$$ \int[(x-1)^{\frac 12}-(x-3)]dx=\frac 23 (x-1)^{\frac32}-\frac12x^2+3x+c $$

I understand why the textbook's answer is right. But I don't understand what I did wrong in mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{3}(x-1)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}(x-3)^2+c &= \frac{2}{3}(x-1)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-6x+9)+c\\ &= \frac{2}{3}(x-1)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}x^2+3x\underbrace{-\frac{9}{2}+c}_{\text{constant}},
\end{align}
so both answers are valid.